# Application crashes when button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

so this is what's happening, I've got two scenes in my storyboard, scene one is a login form, and scene two is a form which calls a NSURLSession (that scene isn't the issue however)

What is happening, is when I click the Login button on the first scene, the app crashes, what should happen is the login credentials should be checked against the (currently hardcoded) user credentials, if they are correct, a segue should send the user to the second scene.

This is the error log data;

> 2014-10-01 17:24:51.454 TotalSMSAPP[15443:446622] -[TotalSMSAPP.ViewController1 activateLogin:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f88d3424620
>   2014-10-01 17:24:51.459 TotalSMSAPP[15443:446622] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TotalSMSAPP.ViewController1 activateLogin:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f88d3424620'

This is the code applicable to the problematic scene;

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ViewController1: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var password: UITextField!


    @IBAction func login(sender: UIButton) {
        if(username.text == "koharu" && password.text == "test"){
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toSMS",sender: self)
        }else{


        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TotalSMSAPP.ViewController1 activateLogin:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f88d3424620'`

This error states that `activateLogin:` is called while you have defined  `login:`. It could happen if you renamed the method. Remove the button action and reconnect it again with  `@IBAction func login(sender: UIButton)`.

Comment: Hahaha cheers. It seems that the editor created two different references at some point, probably due to me getting distracted by someone asking a question LOL. *Blond Mistake* :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have a segue with this identifier.
And also override prepareForSegue method which will help you debug.

Answer (score 0):

When the button is pressed it tries to call the method `activateLogin:`, but you haven't provided one. Probably you connected the button to the `activateLogin:` action and then you renamed it.

Simply go in Interface Builder, remove the reference to the old method and make a new one to `login:` instead.